# Product URL Rewrite troubles in Magento 1.7

Tags: php, magento

My Magento 1.7 installation has a weird problem, All the Products URLs have Category key in them, but the Up-Sell products (on a product's details page) are showing URLs with Category key missing. URLs for related products are ok.

My Magento Settings are as shown below ::

- "Use Categories Path for Product URLs" => YES
- "Create Permanent Redirect for URLs if URL Key Changed" => No
- "Use Parent Category Path for Category URLs" => No

My Products are ::

1. located 2 category level deep, means cat1/cat2/product
2. all product URLs are in this format :: site_url/cat2/product_key
3. One product is appearing under multiple categories

Any help is highly solicited.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution to Include Category Name in Upsell Product's URL ...

I had to modify the file at **my_theme/template/catalog/product/list/upsell.phtml**

And around line number 51, just after the line :

```
<?php if($_link=$this->getIterableItem()):
```

I adde the following lines ::

```
$d = $_link->getData();
$id = $d['entity_id'];
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
$_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]); 
$cat_url = str_replace(".html","",$_category->getUrlPath());
$_url = Mage::getUrl($cat_url).basename($_link->getProductUrl());
```

And Used the **$_url** variable as product's URL. This worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Better use this code where $_categories is an if-function

```
$d = $_link->getData();
$id = $d['entity_id'];
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);
$_categories = $_product->getCategoryIds();
if($_categories) {
    $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_categories[0]);
    $cat_url = str_replace(".html","",$_category->getUrlPath());
    $_url = Mage::getUrl($cat_url).basename($_link->getProductUrl());
}
```

And for output urls:

```
<?php if ($_categories) { echo $_url; }; ?>
```

Otherwise system.log counts errors when articles have no categories.